# OpenCV image conversion from RGB to Grayscale exception

Tags: opencv

I'm getting a strange exception (exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x002EB6CC) when I try to convert a RGB image to Grayscale. Can someone help me?

```
  const cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread(filename, 0)
  cv::Mat gs_rgb(img1.size(), CV_8UC1);
  cv::cvtColor(img1, gs_rgb, CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

Comment: Have you tried with other images? What about other filetypes? This question doesn't have enough info to answer well.

Comment: Please include more information in your question to better describe what is not working. A first step is to make sure your image loaded correctly. Also, you want to pass `CV_BGR2GRAY`, since OpenCV uses BGR ordering by default.

Answer (score 5):

You are loading image as gray scale and trying to convert the gray scale to gray scale again.

The line

```
  const cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread(filename, 0)
```

will load the image

where the second argument

```
=0->CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE->load gray scale
=1->CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR->load color
<0->CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH->Return the loaded image as is (with alpha channel).
```

So either load image as gray scale and use it like,

```
  const cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread(filename, 0)//load gray
```

Or load it as color and then convert to gray scale like,

```
  const cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread(filename, 1);//load color
  Mat gray;//no need of allocation, will allocate automatically.
  cv::cvtColor(img1,gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);//opencv default color order is BGR
```

See more info here in [imread documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread).